# Magento 2.3 : Multiple image upload in admin form ui component?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, uicomponent, image-upload

I am facing issue uploading multiple images.i have implemented single image upload in Magento 2.3 from the admin side using the UI component. 
Thanks for your help
my code is given below.

form code

```
    <field name="restorent_images">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">geolocation</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image Of Restorent</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <!-- <item name="isMultipleFiles" xsi:type="boolean">true</item> -->
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">image</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="ranosys_giolocation/index/upload"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

controller

```
    <?php

namespace Ranosys\GioLocation\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

/**
 * Class Upload
 */
class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * Image uploader
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader
     */
    protected $imageUploader;

    /**
     * Upload constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Ranosys\GioLocation\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
    }

    /**
     * Check admin permissions for this controller
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Ranosys_GioLocation::ranosys_gioLocation');
    }

    /**
     * Upload file controller action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('restorent_images');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
    }
}
```

model

```
    <?php

namespace Ranosys\GioLocation\Model;
/**
 * Catalog image uploader
 */
class ImageUploader
{
    /**
     * Core file storage database
     *
     * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database
     */
    protected $coreFileStorageDatabase;

    /**
     * Media directory object (writable).
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface
     */
    protected $mediaDirectory;

    /**
     * Uploader factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory
     */
    private $uploaderFactory;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * Base tmp path
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $baseTmpPath;

    /**
     * Base path
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $basePath;

    /**
     * Allowed extensions
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $allowedExtensions;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDatabase,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        $baseTmpPath,
        $basePath,
        $allowedExtensions
    ) {
        $this->coreFileStorageDatabase = $coreFileStorageDatabase;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->baseTmpPath = $baseTmpPath;
        $this->basePath = $basePath;
        $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;

    }

    /**
     * Set base tmp path
     *
     * @param string $baseTmpPath
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setBaseTmpPath($baseTmpPath)
    {
        $this->baseTmpPath = $baseTmpPath;
    }

    /**
     * Set base path
     *
     * @param string $basePath
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setBasePath($basePath)
    {
        $this->basePath = $basePath;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowed extensions
     *
     * @param string[] $allowedExtensions
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAllowedExtensions($allowedExtensions)
    {
        $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve base tmp path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBaseTmpPath()
    {
        return $this->baseTmpPath;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve base path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBasePath()
    {
        return $this->basePath;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve base path
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getAllowedExtensions()
    {
        return $this->allowedExtensions;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve path
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param string $imageName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFilePath($path, $imageName)
    {
        return rtrim($path, '/') . '/' . ltrim($imageName, '/');
    }

    /**
     * Checking file for moving and move it
     *
     * @param string $imageName
     *
     * @return string
     *
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function moveFileFromTmp($imageName)
    {
        $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();
        $basePath = $this->getBasePath();

        $baseImagePath = $this->getFilePath($basePath, $imageName);
        $baseTmpImagePath = $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $imageName);
        try {
            $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->copyFile(
                $baseTmpImagePath,
                $baseImagePath
            );
            $this->mediaDirectory->renameFile(
                $baseTmpImagePath,
                $baseImagePath
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('Something went wrong while saving the file(s).')
            );
        }

        return $imageName;
    }


    public function saveFileToTmpDir($fileId)
    {
        $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();
        $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $fileId]);
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions($this->getAllowedExtensions());
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);

        $result = $uploader->save($this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($baseTmpPath));
        if (!$result) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('File can not be saved to the destination folder.')
            );
        }

        $result['tmp_name'] =str_replace("\ ", "/", $result['tmp_name']);

        $result['path'] = str_replace('\ ', '/', $result['path']);
        $result['url'] = $this->storeManager
                ->getStore()
                ->getBaseUrl(
                    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
                ) . $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $result['file']);
        $result['name'] = $result['file'];

        if (isset($result['file'])) {
            try {
                $relativePath = rtrim($baseTmpPath, '/') . '/' . ltrim($result['file'], '/');
                $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->saveFile($relativePath);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e);
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __('Something went wrong while saving the file(s).')
                );
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please share your code and provide error you are getting ?

Comment: ok I had code for single image upload but i need to do multiple i will update code

Comment: @AasimGoriya i have updated code

Comment: please check my ans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use imageUploader instead of fileUploader in your form code xml.

```
<item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">imageUploader</item>
```

So your code is look like below

```
<field name="restorent_images">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">geolocation</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image Of Restorent</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">imageUploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <!-- <item name="isMultipleFiles" xsi:type="boolean">true</item> -->
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">image</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="ranosys_giolocation/index/upload"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

Comment: i have added that but i want for multiple files

Comment: are you not able to see add to Gallery button after this change ?

Comment: its coming like this https://imgur.com/7aRuIcY

Comment: I assume that you are using fileUploader right ?

Comment: ooh, I got. but how will be saving image path to database

Comment: and where image is uploaded

Comment: your code is ok but you just need to change imageUploader only, please check my updated ans for more information.

Comment: and how to select multiple images from here https://imgur.com/a/Tn1dA6I

Comment: using ctrl+ select multiple images

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89604/discussion-between-aasim-goriya-and-adarsh-shukla).

Comment: sir but while editing record images don't show up  in form

Comment: Which version of magento are you using ?

Comment: i am using Magento 2.3

Answer (score 0):

In the Class Upload, Add this line before try catch

```
$imageId = $this->_request->getParam('param_name', 'restorent_images');
```

And replace this line

```
$result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('restorent_images');
```

With

```
$result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir($imageId);
```