# Magento 2: How to implement multiple image uploader in admin form using UI component

Tags: magento2, image-upload, file-upload

I'm using UI component for building admin form. In the form, I have an image uploader field.

Using this uploader, I'm able to select only one image to upload. But I need to upload multiple images.

On referring to Magento docs, `isMultipleFiles` option needs to be true.

```
<field name="image" sortOrder="10" formElement="imageUploader">
<settings>
    <label translate="true">Image</label>
    <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/uploader/image</elementTmpl>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <validation>
        <rule xsi:type="boolean" name="required-entry">true</rule>
    </validation>
</settings>
<formElements>
    <imageUploader>
        <settings>
            <isMultipleFiles>true</isMultipleFiles>
            <validation>
                <rule xsi:type="boolean" active="false" name="required-entry">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <uploaderConfig>
                <param xsi:type="string" name="url">sample/image/upload</param>
            </uploaderConfig>
            <previewTmpl>Module/image-preview</previewTmpl>
        </settings>
    </imageUploader>
</formElements>
```

But still, the uploader is able to select only one image. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

```
<field name="image">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add  Image</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">imageUploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <item name="isMultipleFiles" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">image</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="sample/image/upload"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

Refrence: [Magento 2.3 : Multiple image upload in admin form ui component?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261322/magento-2-3-multiple-image-upload-in-admin-form-ui-component)