# How to upload Multiple images in backend for custom module in magento2

Tags: magento2, multiple-file-upload

Need to upload multiple images for my custom module in admin panel in magento2
for single image its done properly.
but having issue for multiple images.
Can Any one have an idea??

Comment: It will help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261322/magento-2-3-multiple-image-upload-in-admin-form-ui-component

Comment: Which Issue you are facing? And are you looking for the custom form or configuration section?